# hive start tez who fails to connect to yarn

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-tez

I have installed an hadoop cluster with one master and 3 nodes.
hadoop v 3.2.1, hive 3.1.2 and tez 0.10.0

I verified conf files and I can't find why tez is trying to connect to yarn throw localhost:18032
yarn is configured to be on hadoop-master:8032.

I tested directly tez with an example and it connects correctly to yarn

```
hadoop jar tez-examples-0.10.0.jar  orderedwordcount /user/hive/foo.txt /user/hive/tmp/out
```

So, when executing a SQL like insert into ...  I have that log

`2022-10-28 12:36:15,036 INFO  ipc.Client (Client.java:handleConnectionFailure(1010)) - Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:18032. Already tried 9 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)`

Comment: I suggest searching `yarn.resourcemanager.address` property in your cluster and check the values are correct or not.

Comment: Also make sure the value is the same across every node's config files , and that you have set environment variables such as `HADOOP_CONF_DIR` correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered such a situation, no error (because I turned off yarn's memory check). If you don't use the tez engine, you can start hive normally. Later, I think it will be because the memory is too small to start it? I restarted many components of the cluster: including hdfs, yarn, flume, kafa, zookeeper. Then restart hdfs and yarn and zookeeper. Finally, hive can be started.